# Problema con Emulador Nox

Tags: android

Descargué Nox como emulador externo pero cuando intento ejecutar la app de prueba me sale el error de la cap. La versión del sistema android del proyecto de la app. es 7.1.1 del emulador 5.1.1" ¿Que pasa ahí?

[image: Errir mensaje]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambien la versión mínima del SDK a la versión del emulador. No entiendo por que la versión mínima superior no funciona. Pero así logré solucionarlo.